# An Elementary Example from Kosniowski's Course in Algebraic Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am studying the first rudiments of algebraic topology from the wonderful book "A First Course in Algebraic Topology" by Kosniowski. On page 22 I have met the following Figure 4.3 (here reproduced in the bottom part of the picture).

[image]

Kosniowski simply says that the spaces in Figure 4.3(a) and (d) are homeomorphic, with intermediate homeomorphic spaces illustrated in Figure 4.3(b) and (c). Now, Figure 4.3(d) looks to me as a torus where a little disk has been removed, and clearly the space in Figure 4.3(c) is homeomorphic to it. But I cannot interpret the space in Figure 4.3(b) as one homeomorphic to the one in Figure 4.3(c). Maybe I have not correctly understood the picture.

Could someone add some explanation, please?

Thank you very very much for your kind help in advance.

Comment: You stretch the "small ring" until it extends almost all around the big ring.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Dear Michal, I am sorry, but I cannot understand what you mean by "it extends all around the big ring".

Comment: In picture b) the "small ring" sits on top of say 5% of the big ring. Picture c) is the same except that the "small ring" now occupies 90% of the length of the big ring. You can deform one to the other by increasing the 5% to the 90% continuously.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek  Eurekaaaa, I have understood it now!!! Thank you very very ... much Michal! I was stuck because I made a remarkable error of interpration of the picture 4.3(a) just at the beginning. Picture 4.3(a) is "two-dimensional" as to say: it represents two non-overlapping annuli glued together, while I interpreted as a "three-dimensional" picture representing the connected sum of two tori! Thank you very very much again, I would have spent myabe days thinking of this conundrum without your help!